# Why is the screen not clickable when changing backgroundColor on react-native to transparent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a code which will pop up and close the popup with a little animation in it. The problem arises when I add color to the background of the popup. Because when the popup is closed and the background color has changed, the screen can't be clicked.

I thought about removing the background, but I didn't know how. I think setting backgroundColor to transparent will solve my problem. But it only removes the previous color and makes the screen not clickable.

Previously I tried to use if else to close the background, but the animation on the application doesn't even work anymore.

Here is the code I attached:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Animated, KeyboardAvoidingView, Dimensions, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const testScreen = () => {
  const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  const bounceValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(windowHeight)).current;
  const [reportBackgroundColor, setReportBackgroundColor] = useState("");

  const _toggleSubviewAppear = () => {

    var toValue = 0;

    Animated.spring(
      bounceValue,
      {
        toValue: toValue,
        velocity: 3,
        tension: 2,
        friction: 8,
      }
    ).start();
    setReportBackgroundColor("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)");

  };

  const _toggleSubviewDisappear = () => {

    var toValue = windowHeight;

    Animated.spring(
      bounceValue,
      {
        toValue: toValue,
        velocity: 3,
        tension: 2,
        friction: 8,
      }
    ).start();

  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(reportBackgroundColor));

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
        _toggleSubviewAppear();
      }}>
        <View style={{borderRadius: 100, height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'pink', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: "center"}}>
          <Text>
            Click to show
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: reportBackgroundColor, flex: 1, top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute' }}>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: bounceValue }], flex: 1, zIndex: 1000, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} >
          <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0", borderWidth: 1, borderTopLeftRadius: 40, borderTopRightRadius: 40, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
              <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                  _toggleSubviewDisappear();
                  setReportBackgroundColor("transparent");
                }}>
                  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 27, top: 27, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 100, backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#E0E0E0', height: 29, width: 29 }}>
                    <Text>
                      X
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <Text style={{ marginTop: 27, alignSelf: "center", fontSize: 19, color: "#333333" }}>Laporkan Penjual</Text>
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}></View>
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `Animated parent view's`  background color, although you change it to transparent, **it still there** so that couldn't click the bottom view, is there you wand to change backgroundcolor? It seems have to change this one? `backgroundColor: 'white'` And then confirm the animated view truly closed, and the button should be clickable.

Comment: I want to change the background Color to transparent on my screen and clickable. I tried to change to "white" but my screen turned white and I couldn't click on any buttons.

Comment: I means change the backgroundColor at the first line of view? Now I understand, maybe you could set the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` inside's view's background color to another to find out button? And then change the background color to transparent or white. and click the button to try.

Comment: I means if you just transparent the animate's view but it still there, you couldn't touch the bottom of the view's button. only if you remove the view above.

Comment: it will work, but the button or element inside is still bright in color. Whereas I want to make the buttons look like they have been shaded / darker and make those buttons not work when a popup appears.

If you want to see what I want:
[link](https://ibb.co/Zzpynn3)
And this is the result of the code that I ran from your suggestion:
[link](https://ibb.co/PgjsfDj)

Comment: Try to add a state to control those buttons if appears will be disable?(if popup appears `disabel=true` ) and condition function add if (disabel!=true) work .

Comment: if I use something like that, it will be very long and inefficient. While the core problem is how my screen can be clicked back when the popup is closed. When the popup is closed and the screen cannot be clicked, I delete the view component that contains the background color (only the parent), and it works. Means that the way the View component should disappear, while it is the Parent Component of the animation.View itself. If I use a statement with {} / curly braces, the animation.View will also disappear.

Comment: Or use curly braces with condition using state to control after close remove the view?

Comment: Something like :  `{this.state.disabel == true ? null : (<View>...</View>)`   and it will remove after you close the animate with stateState disabel  to true?  and if you want to call it, just set disable false before your animate.